# Order relation in complex measure

Tags: measure-theory

For Lebesgue measure, the measure takes values in $[0, +\infty]$, which is an *ordered* semifield that is order-complete and has both a *greatest* and a *smallest* element. But for a complex measure $\mu: \sum_X\to \mathbb{C}$, where $X$ is non-empty, the target space has no *greatest* element. So is it possible to have *measurable* subsets $A\subset B\in \sum_X$ such that $\mu(A)>\mu(B)>0$? What role does $\infty$, the point of infinity, play here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it *mean* $\mu(A) > 0$ for complex-value $\mu$?

Comment: @mihaild $\mu(A)$ can still happen to be real.

Comment: I don't think people talk about the order relation then.  One usually decomposes the measure to its real and imaginary part and then them to positive and negative parts. People then discuss a corresponding absolute measure, sometimes called the total variation. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalVariation.html .

Comment: @user760 but in general it is not. If your question is if we can have $\mu(A), \mu(B) \in \mathbb R$ s.t. your inequality is true - of course, because it can easily be that $\mu(B \setminus C)$ is real and negative.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Thanks. So it seems there are two types of measures: order-preserving measures, such as Lebesgue measure and spectral measure, and measures with no order-related restrictions, such as complex measures.

Comment: In addition to the comments above, it is quite common in Complex analysis to add a single $\infty$ to $\Bbb C$. with the complements of bounded sets as its neighbhorhoods. This converts the complex plane into the Riemann sphere, with $\infty$ and $0$ being antipodal points. Thus it is possible to consider complex measures with $\infty$ as an allowable measurement.

Answer (score 0):

Since, it looks simpler to answer here than in a longer discussion in the comments I'll add something here and edit if the need arises.

As I said earlier, I don't think people usually talk about the order relation for non-negative measures. In your mind the order relation implies set containment, but this is not true for signed measures where you do have the order relation. For example, if you consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu= \delta_{0}- \delta_{1}$, you get that $\mu(\{0\})>\mu(\{0,1\})$.

For this reason, people take a signed measure $\mu$ and rewrite it to the difference $\mu= \mu^+-\mu^-$, where $\mu^+,\mu^-: \Sigma_X\to [0,\infty]$ are non-negative measures. This is done using [Hahn decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem), which says that you can write $X=P\sqcup N$ such that $\mu^+(N)=0$ and $\mu^-(P)=0$.

For complex measures, you don't have a natural order relation to put on measures. So you just write a complex measure $\mu$ as $\mu=\nu_{Re}+i \cdot \nu_{Im}$
, where $\mu=\nu_{Re}$ and $\nu_{Im}$ are both signed measures. You decompose the latter again to non-negative measures. People then discuss a corresponding absolute measure, sometimes called the total variation. See [Total variation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalVariation.html).

You might want to look at the thread: [Why are measures real-valued?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200326/why-are-measures-real-valued?rq=1).

Finally, I don't think spectral measures are necessarily order preserving in the case where they come from an operator who is self-adjoint.